# Code blocks not working?

Tags: support

I just posted this answer: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/82/163, but my code block (prefixed with 4 spaces, just like on stackoverflow) didn't get shown.

As a workaround I used the backticks to get it to show, but code formatting support should be enabled on sitecore.se.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your code is being interpreted as part of the list item just above it. According to the [Markdown list description](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#list):

> To put a code block within a list item, the code block needs to be indented *twice*—8 spaces or two tabs:
>
> ```
> *   A list item with a code block:
>
>        <code goes here>
> ```

As far as I can tell, the only way to signal to our Markdown parser that the code is *not* supposed to be part of the list is to add another paragraph of text between the last list item and the code:

> 1. Configure DNS appropriately.
> 2. Add a binding in IIS for each hostname.
> 3. Modify the config file `App_Config/Include/SiteDefinition.config` with a new `<Site>` node for each site.
>
> The code:
>
> ```
> <!-- this entry will respond to http://site1.hostname.com/mysite with the /Sitecore/sites/mysite/home node -->
> ```

(Also complicating matters: the first line of code is a valid HTML comment that would normally not be shown in the post if it were not quoted as code.)

Comment: Thank you, that worked.